# Electrical properties of glycol / water mixtures

Tags: reference-request, electrical-properties

I'm looking for a reference on electrical properties (specifically, conductivity) of mixtures of water / ethylene glycol. Specifically, I'm interested in

- How does the electrical conductivity of the mixture depend on the volume fraction of the glycol? Can I use standard formulas (which I also struggle to find) for liquid mixtures? Are there such formulas?
- If there are such formulas, is there a *standard reference* for the electrical properties of ethylene glycol?
- How does the conductivity of the mixture depend on temperature? Does the rule of thumb 2%/°C that is used for water stand also for water/glycol mixtures?

Comment: Try the CRC handbook of physics and chemistry.

Comment: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/142/1/012059/pdf

Would highly suggest to check this paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am no conductivity modelling expert so take what follows with a grain of salt. Also do not hesitate to comment this answer, and I will try to improve it accordingly.

---

Your question consists in **six**(!) questions which I will try to answer below.

#### 1. How does the electrical conductivity of the mixture depend on the volume fraction of the glycol?

You may have a look at the figure below, from Loskutov *et al.*[1], for water / ethylene mixtures at 25°C.

[image: Viscosity and conductivity of a water / glycol mixture at 25°C]

#### 2. & 3. Can I use standard formulas (which I also struggle to find) for liquid mixtures? Are there such formulas?

I must admit my lack of knowledge on this very topic, but the authors in [1] propose a formula for conductivity introducing a physical quantity they called *excess electrical parameter*, however noting that "*excess electrical conductivity is not a universal parameter, so it is introduced for general consideration of different characteristics in a
single scale*".

You may also want to have a look at references [2], into which the author propose two different curve fittings (exponential and quadratic models). However, I fear that these equations are purely experimental. Furthermore, in your case (binary mixture without additional salt), this would lead to R=0 in their formula, for which their fit is not that great (probably due to the actual shape of the conductance shown in the figure above).

Additionally, although I did not find many paper on water / glycol *binary* mixtures, I did find quite a lot of publications on *ternary* mixtures, adding NaCl, CaCl$_2$, carbon nanotubes, and whatnot (see [4] for instance). In the latter cases, determinations of conductivities are also very much empiric.

#### 4. If there are such formulas, is there a standard reference for the electrical properties of ethylene glycol?

I honestly do not know what you mean by *standard reference*. Do you mean a standard setup and / or procedure for measuring it? Like a set of temperature / pressure / purity / cell dimension / apparatus / frequency / voltage? Do you rather refer to the measured conductivity under such conditions / with such a procedure? Both?

#### 5. & 6. How does the conductivity of the mixture depend on temperature? Does the rule of thumb 2%/°C that is used for water stand also for water/glycol mixtures?

Regarding the influence of temperature on said conductivity, I found nought but [3], which studies the influence of temperature on the RF conductivity (1 MHz) and dielectric constant of glycol / water mixtures.

Do you have any reference for this "*rule of thumb*" that you mention?

---

### References

[1] *Molecular Structure of an Ethylene Glycol–Water Solution at 298 K*, Loskutov *et al.* (2018), DOI: [10.1134/S003602441902016X](http://dx.doi.org/10.1134/S003602441902016X)
[2] *Electrical Conductivity Measurements for the Ternary Systems of Glycerol/Sodium Chloride/Water and Ethylene Glycol/Sodium Chloride/Water and Their Applications in Cryopreservation*, Chen *et al.* (2009), DOI: [10.1089/bio.2009.0001](http://dx.doi.org/10.1089/bio.2009.0001)
[3] *RF Conductivity and Dielectric Relaxation Studies on an Ethylene Glycol-Water Mixture*, Saha *et al.* (1999), DOI: [10.1088/0022-3727/32/7/011](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0022-3727/32/7/011)
[4] *Electrical Conductivity Measurements for the Ternary Systems of Glycerol/Sodium Chloride/Water and Ethylene Glycol/Sodium Chloride/Water and Their Applications in Cryopreservation*, Chen *et al.* (2009), DOI: [10.1089/bio.2009.0001](http://dx.doi.org/10.1089/bio.2009.0001)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Across sources for e.g. monoethlyene glycol I found values in disagreement with each other. Typically, they would rate the conductivity to approx $1 \mu S / cm$ but that's not always true.

Comment: For the "rule of thumb": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity_(electrolytic)#Conductivity_versus_temperature

Comment: In the reference [1], the conductivity of water is quite high (1.5 $\mu S/cm$). Could I expect a lower curve in case the conductivity of water is lower?

Comment: @G.Gare, the wikipedia page that you mentioned also states that "This value is broadly applicable for most *salts* at room temperature.", so I guess it may be quite bold of an asumption to believe that it holds for non-salt substances  such as glycol. For your remark on water conductivity: the latter depends on water purity (purer water will have a lower conductivity), so I would guess your expectation is right.

Comment: thanks for your comments. What I mean with "lower curve" is: shall I expect that the "bell effect" or the excess conductivity is also, proportionally, loweR?

Comment: @G.Gare, I am sorry, but I have absolutely no idea... Intuitively, I would tend to say that both phenomena are uncorrelated: the bell effect is likely caused by water / glycol interactions, while the "baseline" conductivity of not-so-pure water is ionic in essence. So I would think that using lower conductivity water should only *translate* the curve down but not *scale* it down (i.e. flatten it). **However** this is pure speculation on my side, and I would advise checking this experimentally if possible.